# PHP Как перенести строку по второй запятой

Tags: php

Есть текст №2 (644) 19 августа, пятница, 2018 год

```
$mytext = "№2 (644) 19 январь, пятница, 2018 год";
$mytext = str_replace(',', ",\r\n", $mytext);
$mytext = str_replace(')', ")\r\n", $mytext);
echo nl2br($mytext);
```

Сейчас получается так

```
№2 (644)
19 августа,
пятница,
2018 год
```

Вопрос такой как сделать перенос строки не всех запятых а только второго ну или последнего, или с конца первого =)

что бы получилось вот так

```
№2 (644)
19 августа, пятница,
2018 год
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
$mytext = "№2 (644) 19 январь, пятница, 2018 год";

$mytext = preg_replace('~(\d{1,2}\s\pL+)|(\d{4}\s\pL{3,4})$~u', "\r\n$1$2", $mytext);

echo $mytext;
```

Результат:

```
№2 (644) 
19 январь, пятница, 
2018 год
```

[См.демо](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f80c35b54a865b42bc91b0c9da833eadeacee48e)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, только подскажите а правильно ли вообще использовать регулярное выражение для такой задачи как у меня?

Comment: Если можно обойтись решением в одну строку, то почему бы и нет? Более того, регулярные выражения как раз и нужны для работы с подстроками.